# Javascript function to remove special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function to replace in a text field special characters and change all text to Uppercase.
If I add the function directly inside a `<script>` tag:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function ...
<script/>
```

the script works as expected.

If I include it as an external file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $dir_js; ?>/plugins/replace.js"></script>
```

Only changing to uppercase works, special characters are not removed.

Any help? What's Wrong?

```
function retiraAcento(palavra,obj)
{
  com_acento = 'áàãâäéèêëíìîïóòõôöúùûüçÁÀÃÂÄÉÈÊËÍÌÎÏÓÒÕÖÔÚÙÛÜÇ';
  sem_acento = 'aaaaaeeeeiiiiooooouuuucAAAAAEEEEIIIIOOOOOUUUUC';
  nova='';
  for(i=0;i<palavra.length;i++) {
    if (com_acento.search(palavra.substr(i,1))>=0) {
      nova+=sem_acento.substr(com_acento.search(palavra.substr(i,1)),1);
    }
    else {
      nova+=palavra.substr(i,1);
    }
  }
  obj.value = nova.toUpperCase();
}

$(":input").live('blur', function() {
  retiraAcento(this.value, this);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that your external file is not the same encoding as the main file. You should make sure that both files have UTF-8 encoding, plus you should also make certain that whatever server you are using is serving the files with the right content type.

If the files have different encoding this would cause the problems you are experiencing, due to the fact that `á` typed in your input would not match the `á` in your javascript file — and so could not be found and removed.

Another way round this would be to not use hardcoded values in your external JavaScript, check using RegExp instead and information found here:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#grapheme

Comment: @user2123738 no problem, if you ever get strange character comparisons always check your encoding ;)

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap your code on the ready event :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(":input").live('blur', function() {
    retiraAcento(this.value, this);
  }); 
});
```

Comment: I assume that the file is included properly, correct? If you add an `alert("here")` in the code you actually see that?

Comment: yes, i have added : alert("here"); below obj.value = nova.toUpperCase(); and box appears...
also, uppercase work right...